# Add password to openssl .pem file from -password

Tags: encryption, openssl, pem

I am generating a `.pem` file using openssl using the command:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key.pem 4096
```

It is working great but when I do this:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key.pem 4096 -password pass:abcd
```

It is still asking me for a password in the terminal and not automatically taking the supplied password.

I've tried generating certificates before and it works for them eg.

```
openssl pkcs12 -name username -inkey cert/key.key -in abc.pem -export -out cert.p12 -password pass:abcd
```

Comment: Please note that encrypting private keys that way is extremely insecure, because openssl uses a ridiculously weak algorithm to derive the symmetric key encryption key from the password. In other words, openssl's PBKDF is seriously flawed. For a starting point, see here https://web.archive.org/web/20190528100132/https://latacora.singles/2018/08/03/the-default-openssh.html and here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59136/can-i-add-a-password-to-an-existing-private-key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're very close to the goal ! Key size must be the last parameter and `-password` replace with `-passout`

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key.pem -passout pass:abcd 4096
```